# Disabling Vim command line feedback messages

Tags: vim

- `"foo.py" 72L, 1353C written`
- `1 more line; before #8 16:00:37`

When I enter [Goyo mode](https://github.com/junegunn/goyo.vim), I dislike any distractions, and the final thing I'd like to disable are these spurious messages Vim put in the command line.

Is there a way to disable all of them?

#### EDIT

Submitted a feature request issue: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/557.

Comment: @romainl I've just set it to 999 and got a report for a undo of a single line change...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
:set report=99999
:set shortmess=astWAIc
```

The first will  *reduce* the number of messages, the second will *shorten* messages. But there's no option to completely turn these off, as that would be (at least in my opinion) very bad usability.

It would be nice to have a default *highlighting group* (currently `Normal` is used for most messages), so that you could make the messages less visually distracting (e.g. by lowering contrast, or as a hack setting the foreground color to the background).

Comment: I guess this is the answer until there's a de facto one.